# Why does the From Dust 3D game run on Chrome only?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, webgl

There is a new **web based 3D game** called **[FROM DUST](http://from-dust.ubisoft.com/)**. It's available for **the web browser Google Chrome**, but I would like to know why this game is not available for Firefox, Opera and Safari too. All those browsers have **WebGL 3D support**, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not based on WebGL but OpenGL and Native Client (NaCl)